# How to fix problem with WACK "Error Found: The private code signing test encountered the following errors:"

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, appxmanifest, wack

[image]

I have a problem whem I testing my app in WACK / (Windows app certification kit ) The type of problem

---

Private code signing
Error Found: The private code signing test encountered the following errors:
The package contains code signing keys MyProj_StoreKey.pfx.

Impact if not fixed: Including private code signing keys in the package violates the Microsoft Store certification requirements.

How to fix: Remove any private code signing keys (e.g. .pfx and .snk files) from the package.[WACK test have a bad result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3m9R.jpg)

Comment: Did you [associate your app with the Microsoft Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devapps/step-1--create-a-uwp-device-app#associate-your-app-with-the-microsoft-store) before packaging it?

Comment: Yes of course))

Comment: Does your local WACK work normally? You could create an simple demo,associate with Store and package it to test if your local WACK can work normally.

Comment: But I  created  new  UWP project , after that a added my certificate, and project 
passed the test successfully . Maybe I set something up wrong ?

Comment: With my local WACK  I dont have problem , because i havent  problem with other projects and testing other project by WACK

Comment: Could you check its package.appxmanifest with the others projects'? If it is normal, you could upload your package to the Store directly. There is an online WACK for each publishing app, the local WACK is optional.